# A good book for Quantum Cryptography

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations

I am interested in Quantum Information and Cryptography in particular. I have gone through Nielsen's text and Preskill's notes. Can someone suggest to me some good text for Quantum Cryptography?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't really many books on quantum cryptography.

The only one I am aware of is a book titled [Applied Quantum Cryptography](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-04831-9) (C. Kollmitzer and M. Pivk, eds., Springer, 2010).

The Nielsen and Chuang book has a few pages dedicated to quantum cryptography in chapter 12.6.

However, I would recommend the following review papers on quantum cryptography as opposed to textbooks:

- Quantum Cryptography. N. Gisin et al., [*Rev. Mod. Phys.* **74** no. 1, 145 (2002)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.74.145), [arXiv:quant-ph/0101098](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0101098).
- The security of practical quantum key distribution. V. Scarani et al., [*Rev. Mod. Phys.* **81** no. 3, 1301 (2009)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.81.1301), [arXiv:0802.4155](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.4155).

The first is the first review of the field, so it will provide a good introduction but is not up to date in terms of the latest developments. The second is a more extensive and mature review, but also more advanced.